# Add line breaks to dynamic text in an html email sent via Sendgrid's API

Tags: html, css, sendgrid, line-breaks

I am inserting dynamic text in my HTML email that has got numbering and subsequent line breaks. The SendGrid tag is: `{{insert emailData.data.copy3 'default=' }}`
The text I am inserting looks like this:

```
The attached proposal covers the following:
 
1. Overview
2. How the Fund contributes to systemic change

Please indicate  your acceptance by clicking on this button
```

However, it is displaying like this in my email:

```
The attached proposal covers the following: 1. Overview 2. How the Fund contributes to systemic change Please indicate  your acceptance by clicking on this button
```

Please assist so that my line breaks displays correctly.

Comment: Can you share the HTML code that you are currently using?

Comment: @IObert This is the html code with the dynamic tag for SendGrid:  <p style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-alt: 22.5px;"><span style="font-size:15px;">{{insert emailData.data.copy3 'default=' }}</span></p>

Answer (score 0):

In HTML whitespace, beyond spaces between words, is ignored by rendering engines. You need to lay out your document with HTML to make it render correctly.

In the case of your email copy, to make it appear like you wish, you need to include HTML to lay it out. This should work:

```html
<p>The attached proposal covers the following:
<ol>
  <li>Overview</li>
  <li>How the Fund contributes to systemic change</li>
</ol>
<p>Please indicate your acceptance by clicking on this button</p>
```

How you generate this HTML is up to you. You could, for example, run your original text through a markdown parser and generate the HTML from that text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @philnash, however that wont work as its text thats dynamically inserted via API call into a SendGrid template. My code for that section plus the dynamic tag is:  <p style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-alt: 22.5px;"><span style="font-size:15px;">{{insert emailData.data.copy3 'default=' }}</span></p>

Comment: When you dynamically insert that text into the SendGrid template, can you parse it as Markdown and insert generated HTML at that point? Otherwise, you could try wrapping the whole thing in `<pre>` tags, with added style to set the right font.

Comment: Thanks @philnash, however I cant add it into sendgrid as marked down. I attempted <pre> but it messed my styling quite severely. This is where the tag inserts the text in my code. Where would the place be for pre:

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you add it into SendGrid as markdown, but that you parse it as markdown and emit it as HTML before you send it to SendGrid so that it is placed in the page as HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work in sendgrid. Have you managed to do that via integromat/make and then into sendgrid?

Comment: I feel like there is more to your setup here that hasn’t been described. Could you take a step back and describe how you send your emails including where you get this content from?

Comment: I have the dynamic data stored in airtable. I pull it from Airtable with Make, compile the json for the sendgrid api call, and then send it to sendgrid. Is that helpful?

Comment: Could you use the [Markdown processor in Make](https://www.make.com/en/help/app/markdown) to translate the text from Airtable to HTML before sending it to SendGrid?